# How to chain a onSnapshot in Firebase firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to chain a `.onSnapshot` listener but not sure how to do it.

**Context:** Using [Firebase firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) with [React](https://reactjs.org/) and a reducer to manage the local data.

I have an API object that stores all my API calls and deals with the reducer, and the "components" (using react) uses my API object to query.
Example:

```js
// My api object
const myApiCall = {
   listenToComments: () =>{
     // <-- Here I would like to do some background reducer stuff when a new comment is added...
     return db.collection(`post/comments`)
   }
}

// My component

const listenToComments = myApiCall.listenToComments.onSnapshot((snap)=>{
  // Do some visual stuff here
})
```

**How can I listen to the `.onSnapshot` in both `myApiCall` and in my component?**

*Bearing in mind that the unsubscribe would be done in my component hopefully*

Comment: You can try reaching out to the Firebase team [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact)